# Bizarre Javascript Result

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, null, undefined

Why does this piece of code return `- null -` when it should return `- -` by my understanding - it seems to be treating `null` like a string.

```
var testvar = null;
alert(" - "+testvar+" - ");
```

Thats it.  The same goes for `undefined`. I need this to work as I have an array, and I loop to loop through the array, and add each item to a variable, which is a string.

I have this:

```
//'resp' variable is a JSON response, decoded with JSON.parse.  This part works fine.
var addOnEnd=null;
for (item in resp) {
    console.log(">"+item);
    addOnEnd += item+"\n";
}
```

The console.log reads what I'd expect - a list of all the items in the response.

However, if I alert(`addOnEnd`) after the for loop, it returns 'undefined' (literally the string) and then the rest of the array as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this:

`alert(" - " + (testvar || "") + " - ");`

...and this...

`addOnEnd += (item || "") + "\n";`

**You will also need to initialize addOnEnd as an empty string instead of null.**

This way, if the value is undefined (which when evaluated as a boolean returns false) it'll use the 'default' value of an empty string.

Comment: Thanks!  The alert() snippet works on the first example, but the second one doesn't, which is weird because it's basicaly the same code.

Comment: Change `addOnEnd = null;` to `addOnEnd = '';`, updated my answer :)

Comment: Looks like @Theodore spotted that - I didn't :)

Comment: Thank you!!  I knew it would be something simple.  I've been hopping aruond PHP, HTML, CSS, MySQL(i), and messing with JS/jQuery, so I'm not completely focused on the way one language works.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The result is correct. You are seeing the `toString` value of `null` and `undefined`.

If you want to substitute an empty string, then do that.

```
var testvar = null;
alert(" - "+ (testvar == null ? "" : testvar) +" - ");
```

and

```
var addOnEnd="";
for (item in resp) {
    item = item == null ? "" : item;
    console.log(">"+item, resp[item]);
    addOnEnd += item+"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The null value is coerced to the string "null" when catentated (added) to a string.
What you want is this.

```
var addOnEnd="";
for (item in resp) {
    console.log(">"+item);
    addOnEnd += item +"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with your data.

```
var testvar = null;
alert(" - "+testvar+" - ");
// RESULT "- null -" --> as expected.  

var addOnEnd=null;
for (item in {key: "val1", key2: "val2"}) {
  console.log(">"+item);
   addOnEnd += item+"\n"; 
}
alert(addOnEnd)
//result (nullKey1\nKey2)
```

Comment: Just tried that, same result unfortunately.  I tried your sample data and the script returned `nullkeykey2`.

Comment: @Jaxo -- that is what it /should/ return.  According to your question, it returned **`undefined`** followed by the key values.  I set up my example to show it should return `null` instead of `undefined`. If you wish to get rid of the `null` then do this: `var addOnEnd="";` instead.